# Hide a marklogic database to specific user (permissions)

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm using Marklogic 8 and I want to restrict the visibility of the my databases. How can I hide a database (for example the "security" one) to a specific user ? This user isn't an administrator but has access to qconsole.

Thanks :)
Romain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to hide the existence of a database from a user who can see other ones. The security model can be used very effectively to prevent the user from seeing the content of the database, however. In fact, this would be the default case. A user who only has the role "qconsole-user" will be able to connect to Query Console, but will not be able to see content in the Security database (or any other database, unless that role has been granted "read" access).